# if statment in while loop partially working

Tags: python

so I was doing one of the exercises to practice python (sorry guys, just learning). Exercise is asking to do it in a while loop. So I did, unfortunately, it doesn't fully work and I have no idea why, as a similar exercise I did is working properly (in while loop as well using keyboard).

```
import keyboard
    
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        try:
            speed_1 = int(input('What was your speed an hour? '))
            time_1 = int(input('For how long have you been driving? Please input your time in minutes. '))
            distance_1 = (speed_1 / 60) * time_1
            print('Distance you have traveled is ' + str(round(distance_1, 2)) + ' km.')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('You need to use numbers.')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
        try:
            distance_2 = int(input('How far do you want travel? Enter in km. '))
            time_2 = int(input('How long do you have to get there? Enter in minutes. '))
            speed_2 = time_2 / distance_2 * 100
            print('You need to drive ' + str(round(speed_2, 2)) + ' km/h to get there on time.') 
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('You need to use numbers.')
    elif keyboard.read_key() != '1' and keyboard.read_key() != '2':
        break
```

As you can see this is a basic speed, distance calculator. If I press one it will work, if I press 2 it doesn't work at all.. just get stuck not doing anything, pressing any other key works just fine.. it closes a program. What have I done wrong? Any ideas? I know this is probably not worth it to waste my time on it, as it is only exercise, but I've tried to find out why I can't do it that way and why it does work ok apart from when I press 2.

EDIT:
just realized, if I press 2 nothing will happen, but if I will press 1 or any other button after pressing 2, it will either proceed with if or it will close the program.

Comment: Are you sure that pressing 1 work? [Documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.is_pressed) suggests that hotkey is typed

Comment: Note as well, your final `elif` is not necessary: if you reached it, you know the key isn't 1 or 2, so just use `else`.

Comment: 1 is working fine, it was else at the beginning but I was trying everything to make 2 work with no effect and didn't change it back.. 2 is just stuck..

Comment: Try debugging it.  Use a debugger  and press 2.

Comment: I did, that's when it gets stuck, nothing happens after pressing 2, when it supposed proceed with asking questions to calculate speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few approaches and I did make it work. Previously it didn't work probably as if statement in combination with keyboard.is_pressed don't really go well together. it may use 100% cpu or just get stuck (according to what I found online).

```
import keyboard

print('If you want me to tell you how far you traveled, press 1.')
print('If you want to find out how fast you need to drive to get somewhere on time, press 2. ')

def on_1():
    try:
        speed_1 = int(input('What was your speed an hour? '))
        time_1 = int(input('For how long have you been driving? Please input your time in minutes. '))
        distance_1 = (speed_1 / 60) * time_1
        print('Distance you have traveled is ' + str(round(distance_1, 2)) + ' km.')
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to use numbers.')
    
def on_2():
    try:
        distance_2 = int(input('How far do you want travel? Enter in km. '))
        time_2 = int(input('How long do you have to get there? Enter in minutes. '))
        speed_2 = distance_2/ time_2 * 60
        print('You need to drive ' + str(round(speed_2, 2)) + ' km/h to get there on time.')
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to use numbers.')

keyboard.add_hotkey('1', on_1)
keyboard.add_hotkey('2', on_2)

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.wait('1'):
            break
        elif keyboard.wait('2'):
            break
    finally:
        break
```

This is a code that actually worked. Posting just in case if in future someone else will get stuck with a similar issue.
Also, I fixed the calculation for '2'. Didn't realise earlier I've done it the other way round.